# Problem in mounting with Gparted

Tags: dual-boot, mount, gparted, ntfs

I have come up with a problem with mounting an NTFS filesystem of a dual-booting laptop:

[image: 1]

Comment: Please don't just dump an image. Explain exactly what you were doing and copy the error message into your question so that it can be searchable. Did you install the packages that the error message mentions?

Comment: Is this partition where Windows is installed and is Windows set up to use "Fast Start"? Without more information it is difficult to say what is wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: @terdon I was trying to retrieve a file from the Windows partition. But I'm unable to mount the drive. I checked with inbuilt "Disks" utility still no help.

Comment: @user68186 I haven't enabled "Fast Startup".But "Secure Boot" is enabled in BIOS.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain all of these details. You don't show how you attempted to mount, nor what happened when you tried. You're just showing a screenshot that we need to open in a new tab to read. The easier you make it for people to understand your question, the more likely it is that they will try and answer.

Comment: It is on by default. In Windows go to **All Control Panel Items >> Power Options >> Choose What the power button does>>** Uncheck **"Turn on fast startup" (recommended)**

Comment: Check as well whether or not ntfs-3g is installed on your Ubuntu. Gparted asks for it and you need it to mount NTFS formatted drives. In terminal: `sudo apt search ntfs-3g | grep installed` if not, install it with `sudo apt install ntfs-3g`.